# Python TCP raw socket not listening on lo (localhost/ 127.0.0.1)

Tags: python, sockets, localhost

I created a simple packet sniffer using raw socket in Python.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

while True:
    print s.recvfrom(1600)
```

The internet traffic it's showing. But when I turn the primary network interface down and send syn packets using scapy through the `lo` interface (source and destination 127.0.0.1), There's nothing printed.

Basically I create and send 10 syn packets using scapy whose source and destination is 127.0.0.1, which is visible in wireshark. But not in this sniffer. I thought there might be a problem of the length. So I set the buffer size to a syn packet's size i.e. 74 (`s.recvfrom(74)`), but still nothing. As soon as I turn the primary network interface up again, it shows all the TCP traffic.

I need to turn off the network interface so that I won't receive any other traffic other than my own created one.

Where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: Because your level is `0x000`, need create socket `0x003`(ETH_ALL). But a question: "how to receive packet without data ?" And you need listen `loopback` but all packet not is yours. Automatically ignored others packets on internet interface if incoming packet isn't yours !

Comment: With ETH_ALL as per @dsgdfg's answer, it'll receive the Ethernet header and it'll sniff all UDP, ICMP, TCP packets. What I'm sending in the `loopback` is TCP only. So if I want to listen to that what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux :

```
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(3))
soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 2**30)
soc.bind(("eth0",0x0003))
```

Need to open `RAW` not `TCP`.

Edit for comment :

```
a = soc.recvform(65565)[0]
h = binascii.hexlify(a)
if h[24:30] == "080045" and h[46:48] == "06":
# h[24:30] == "080045" Means IP (Type field of Ethernet Header
#               combined with IP Version and IP header length)
# h[46:48] == "06" Means TCP (Ip Protocol field of IP Header)

    #do something with TCP packet
```

**"080045" mean :**

`0800` = IP
`4` = IP version (IPv4)
 `5` = Header length (5 words of 4 bytes each)

Comment: It'll capture all UDP, ICMP, TCP packets. Which I don't want as there I've to parse the packet and add a filter to get only TCP. Is it possible to listen to only TCP packets in all interfaces or specific interface whichever I mention.

Comment: Can you explain the numeral part: `08004500`?  Generally the `24`th byte is the `IP Protocol` field and for TCP it should be `06`. It's a single byte, so It won't be affected by the network byte order. Can you please explain?

Comment: And one more thing, You are binding the socket to `eth0`. How can it be able to listen on `lo`?

Comment: You try dump your loopback packets but already you own packets. Check which app used TCP connection and save anywhere(or clone+redirect to any buffer point). `0x0800` is `IP`,`4500` is `Header size and proto ident`  so you can't received  any `TCP` packets without this header. You are right `06` mean `TCP` but `how will be sure you received right length packets for scanning 'sub header'`. `06` is second filter for analyzed incoming packets !

Comment: Thanks. `0800` is the Type field of Ethernet which says it's IP. `4` is the IP version. `5` is the IP Header length which is 5 words of 4 bytes each. Rest `00` is for ECN Field which is not required. So `080045` will be enough. Then we have to check again for TCP with the IP protocol field. So edited your answer accordingly. Wait till the edit is accepted by the moderator. Thanks for this answer.